# Training loss goes up and down regularly. Weight changes but performance remains the same. What should I do?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions

As you can see in the picture, when the loss reaches 1.54, it goes up and then drops to the same number again and again. But if I reduce the learning rate, the loss is maintained around 1.6, and goes neither up nor down.

[image: Training loss]

Comment: We are talking about a 0.2 difference between min and max. Is this significant for your problem?

Comment: I want the loss keep going down to zero, rather than jump up and down.

Comment: You already figured out that if you change the learning rate the loss stabilizes, so that may be a better choice for your problem. And it looks like the loss won't go much further down than this. Also your loss is lowest right at the start, implying that you may be just wasting your time using more iterations because you are not gaining anything.

Comment: Is there no other possibility here？The weight of the parameter is still changing largely in every epoch.

Comment: What is "the weight of the parameter"? Which parameter? How is it weighted? Why is changing a large amount important?

Comment: Some liner functions' weight and bias, they're learning parameters. I described wrongly before.

Comment: 1.6 seems to be a magic number for me, too. I am stuck in the same problem. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

As it's also pointed out in the comments, it seems the network is not learning any more. The up and downs in the loss are probably because you're around a local minimum and the learning rate is relatively large for that neighbourhood so reducing it stabilises your loss.